# Adobe Flash CS6 won't Export Animated Gif - How do on the main timeline?

Tags: animation, adobe-flash, gif, cs6

I am using Adobe Flash CS6. I have my .fla attached for you. Simple movie. I want to however export it as a GIF and the animation just does not work. It exports a static file. Someone mentioned above the first timeline - how do I do this?

Download the fla ([here](http://gc-cdn.com/star.fla))

Comment: Use **Export Movie** not **Export Image** and choose the Animated GIF format from the list (which should include quicktime/swf/etc.), but you don't have much control over quality/dithering which is horrible. For bet quality results, John's advice is the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about Flash exporting, but a workaround I use in AE is to export a PNG image sequence and create the animated GIF in Photoshop.

Hope that helps

Comment: Appreciate the response. The work around is to place the timeline MovieClip of each frame in the main time line. So the moment the script timeline start - your animation starts. You cannot have a movieClip or a `play()` the only issues with your method it is time consuming with many images. An alternate is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599648/jquery-combine-a-selection-of-pngs-to-one-image-timeline-animation

Comment: Again, not too sure about the Flash stuff, but regarding the comment about it being time consuming: In PS you'd only select/open the first image (auto loading the rest as a sequence), so even though you'd have a folder full of PNG's, the actual process isn't any more time consuming than opening and then saving a single image in PS.

Comment: You can either export the image sequence or an animated gif in Flash. The image sequence works just like it does in AE. One of the other things is once you export a sequence you have more control over color palette (for web optimization) in PS than you do with Flash alone.

Answer (score 2):

You can also go to File > Export > Export Movie > Make sure to set the file to 'Animated GIF' not 'Gif Sequence.'

Comment: You still need to a few steps before making a simple movie. The timeline comments here are correct in my experience in this. Simply using `play()` on a MovieClip is not going to do it

Comment: Brilliant. Just what I needed. Works in Flash CC.

Answer (score 2):

Change GIF **Playback settings** From Static to Animated. 
go to Publish Settings > Gif Image > Playback : Animated | you can use Loop continues or Times.Then Publish

Answer (score 2):

The animated gif export will only export the frames on the main stage.  Meaning you need to have a graphic symbol on the main stage with the total frames.  If you have a MovieClip instead of a Graphic symbol, it will only export the first frame of the mc.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better/easier way, that took me about 5 minutes (because I wasn't familiar with your file).

Here are the steps:

1. On the main timeline, put your cursor on Frame 40 in the top layer and press F5 to extend the timeline.
2. Press "V" to show the instance properties, and then change the symbol type (of the instance on the stage, not the symbol in the library) to a Graphic symbol.
3. Double-click the instance on the stage to open it. Select Frame 40 in all 3 layers, and press F5 again.
4. One at a time, select each layer. Press V to get the instance on that layer. Change it from a MovieClip to a Graphic Symbol.
5. Publish your gif.

Comment: Can this be replicated and not just on my case. As in not case by case.

Comment: Sorry, been on vacation. The Graphic symbol time is there to allow you to synchronize various parallel timelines without code. http://active.tutsplus.com/articles/general/flashs-underrated-graphic-symbol/

Answer (score 0):

It is to be noted that on Windows 8.1 animated Gifs will not play. I installed GifViewer to view animated gifs. The Publish Settings in Flash worked for me. Also to be noted that gradients are not translated well in animated gifs.

Comment: Do you have a proof for that?