# Why is the gif version of this flash movie not working?

Tags: gif, adobe-flash

I am creating a flash banner but when I publish it (or export it) as gif, doesnt show all the layers.
I am aware that the answer must be somewhere in this post [Adobe Flash CS6 won't Export Animated Gif - How do on the main timeline?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/12604/408) But I still do not understand it. Especially since the file is missing and I have no clue to what the users refer by 'frame 40' (i know it is a frame, I just dont know what makes this specific frame special). So do you have any advice to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently building a large gif file of timelapse of a building being constructed and it works no problems when exported. I would suggest you check thoroughly that all your layers that you want to see have their own animation frame assigned and also check the frame duration for the particular layer.

Comment: You were right about checking (quote)  thoroughly that all my layers that I want to see have their own animation frame assigned and also check the frame duration for the particular layer. Moreover, apparently only frames of main timeline appear on gif format.